# Can I convert an int to string then count the number of digits?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I know the common way to count the digits of an int is using a loop, and keep dividing by 10 until it's gone. I'm curious that can I first convert the int into a string and then count the length of the string to get the number of digits (assume there are only positive ints)?

If this method is possible, then what is the difference between using a loop?

Comment: You're asking an optimization question without attempting to do any profiling to verify your assumptions. You assume that a loop is somehow inherently slow. What you seem to be forgetting is that compilers don't directly translate your C++ code into machine code. The C++ code's meaning is extracted from it, and the compiler generates machine code that has the same meaning. **This doesn't imply at all that the generated code will do the same things that you coded in C++, only that the effects will be the same**. What does it really mean? Oftentimes, loops vanish. Profile, profile, profile.

Comment: I usually convert whole int to string first, just because this method is more straightforward,understandable and maintainable,also I hate to hardcode "10" in the int to string method.

Comment: You may want to look at [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/andreialexandrescu1/three-optimization-tips-for-c) from a presentation that Andrei Alexandrescu gave regarding optimization -- one of the examples he used and analyzed was exactly counting digits in a base 10 number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can. NO, you don't want to actually do it**. It will be 2 orders of magnitude (~100x) slower than using the loop. Why? Because integer to string conversion not only has to execute some sort of a loop to generate the string's digits, but also has to allocate *and* deallocate the heap to hold the string, unless the string has some sort of a small-string optimization.

In most cases, people would consider your approach to be an ugly hack. If you want to count digits in an integer, you don't even need a loop:

```
constexpr int digits(int32_t x) {
  return 
    (x < 0 ? digits(-x) :
    (x < 10 ? 1 :   
    (x < 100 ? 2 :   
    (x < 1000 ? 3 :   
    (x < 10000 ? 4 :   
    (x < 100000 ? 5 :   
    (x < 1000000 ? 6 :   
    (x < 10000000 ? 7 :  
    (x < 100000000 ? 8 :  
    (x < 1000000000 ? 9 :  
    10))))))))));  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: GCC can do better: `template<class T>
static constexpr size_t digits() noexcept
{
  return static_cast<size_t>( std::log10(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) ) + 1;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this method is possible.
The difference is that there is an extra step involved if you convert to string first. The string conversion actually does something similar to the loop you described.

Here is an example how to count integer digits via string length:

```
#include <string>

int number_of_digits(int number) {
    // Using C++11
    return std::to_string(number).length();
}
```

Comment: Since there is one extra step, this method is actually slower than using the loop?

Comment: Do note that `std::to_string()` is new in C++11. For older versions, you can use `std::ostringstream` instead: `std::ostringstream oss; oss << number; return oss.str().length();`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `itoa()` function (in this example below, `_itoa_s()` is a *safe* version of `itoa()`). This function basically transforms an integer to a string (itoa=integer to alphabet).

Here's an example:

```
int number;
char temp[12];
cout << "Enter your number: ";
cin >> number;

//itoa(number, temp, 10);
//_itoa_s(number, temp, 12, 10);
_itoa_s(number, temp, 10);

cout << "The number of digits is: " << strlen(temp) << endl;
```

`itoa()` takes 3 parameters: the number you're going to convert (`number`), the buffer where the number will be held after the conversion (`temp`), and the numeral system to which you're converting to (`10` is for base-10, aka decimal numeral system).

`_itoa_s()` takes a 4th parameter, the size of the buffer.  There is also a templated version of `_itoa_s()` specifically for static arrays (which is used in the example above). It takes 3 parameters, letting the compiler deduce the buffer size for the 4th parameter.

Also, I chose 12 characters for the `temp` buffer because the max value of a integer is 2,147,483,647, which has 10 digits, plus room for a null terminator and some extra alignment.

Comment: `temp` contains no data, and certainly is not null-terminated, when `_itoa()` is called, so the use of `strlen()` in the third parameter is wrong in this context (not to mention it is the wrong value for `_itoa_s()` input anyway), and memory will be corrupted when `_itoa_s()` tries to write beyond the bounds of `temp`. The correct code should be more like this: `char *temp = new char[16]; _itoa_s(number, temp, 16, 10); cout << ... << strlen(temp) << ...; delete[] temp;`, or simply: `char temp[16] = {0}; _itoa_s(number, temp, 10); cout << ... << strlen(temp) << ...;`

Comment: Thanks for correcting me,I will correct my code so it won't give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious divide-by-10 method will return 0 for an input of 0, which may or may not be what you want. Other than that, both methods will return the same, but divide-by-10 is *much* faster.

If you use std::string as I do in the example below (which allocates memory), then the divide-by-10 method is easily hundreds of times faster.

```
int numlen_using_divide_by_10(int n) {
  int ret = 0;
  for (; n; n /= 10) ++ret;
  return ret;
}

int numlen_using_string(int n) {
  return std::to_string(n).size();
}
```